# How to do unit testing for nested "using" statements in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm working with big legacy projects.
I've started writing unit tests with xUnit. 
Also, I'm using the Moq framework.
I've read a lot of articles here, but have not found a clear answer. I stuck with understanding how can I do mocks for two IDisposable objects inside a tested method? The method I would like to test:

```cs
public class SomeService: ISomeService
{
  ...
  public async Task<Settings> GetSettings(UserIdentity user)
    {
        SettingsDBModel dbModel;
        using (DBHelperAsync dbHelper = new DBHelperAsync(user))
        {
            using (DBHelperReaderAsync reader = await dbHelper.ExecuteReader("Stored procedure Name", new { UserID = user.UserID }))
            {
                dbModel = await reader.GetResult<SettingsDBModel>();
            }
        }
        var settings = new Settings(dbModel);
        return settings;
    }
  ...
}
```

I want to `reader.GetResult()` method returns some fake data. Any thought how should be implemented of mocks for DBHelperAsync and DBHelperReaderAsync objects?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the extra braces/indentation here. Just stack them.

Comment: You'd need to inject the `DBHelperAsync`.

Comment: @juharr, actually OP shouldn't inject the `dbHelper` itself, since the method is supposed to be the owner/disposer of it--not the client of the method or the DI. Hence the class needs to inject a `DBHelperFactory` with which the method can create its own fresh `DBHelperAsync` instance. The factory method can then be mocked to return a mocked `DBHelperAsync`.

Comment: I second @GoodNightNerdPride approach. factory abstraction to be injected which will create the disposable dependency

Comment: The class under test should be refactored to decouple it from the `DBHelperAsync` implementation concern. An abstract explicit dependency should be injected and configured accordingly for run time code. The would now allow the class  under test to be flexible enough to be easily tested in isolation.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes, that's an even better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class under test should be refactored to decouple it from the `DBHelperAsync` implementation concern. *Classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions*.

An abstract explicit dependency should be injected and configured accordingly for run time code. The would now allow the class  under test to be flexible enough to be easily tested in isolation. *(Explicit Dependency Principle).*

If the legacy classes are unable to be modified then they should be wrapped in abstraction that can be modified and then injected into the classes under test.

The provided code above needs a `IDBHelperAsyncFactory` abstraction that would be injected into the class and used to create the disposable `DBHelperAsync` which should have also been derived from a disposable abstraction `interface IDBHelperAsync : IDisposable`.

That would allow those abstractions to be easily mocked/stubbed while testing.